# how to spy on dispatch on fetch/middleware method

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js, vue-test-utils

I'm trying to test a simple page

```
<template>
  <HomeTemplate />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({
  async fetch(context) { // or middleware(context)
    await context.store.dispatch('categories/index')
  }
})
</script>
```

I would like to spy on dispatch and know if everything went perfectly, 
so i triedbut first I tried to spy on just the action:

```js
import { Wrapper, shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Vuex, { Store } from 'vuex'
import HomePage from './index.vue'
import { CategoriesState } from '@/store/categories'

const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(Vuex)

describe('HomePage', () => {
  type Instance = InstanceType<typeof HomePage>
  let wrapper: Wrapper<Instance>

  let store: Store<CategoriesState>

  const mockIndex: jest.Mock = jest.fn()

  beforeAll(() => {
    store = new Vuex.Store({
      modules: {
        categories: {
          namespaced: true,
          actions: { index: mockIndex }
        }
      }
    })

    wrapper = shallowMount(HomePage, {
      stubs: ['HomeTemplate'],
      localVue,
      store
    })
  })

  it('should call vuex action to fetch categories', () => {
    expect(mockIndex).toHaveBeenCalledWith('categories/index')
  })
})
```

considering that the `fetch()` or `middleware()` method receives the [nuxt context](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch), I tried to mock it

```js
import { Wrapper, shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import HomePage from './index.vue'

describe('HomePage', () => {
  type Instance = InstanceType<typeof HomePage>
  let wrapper: Wrapper<Instance>

  const mockIndex: jest.Mock = jest.fn()

  beforeAll(() => {
    wrapper = shallowMount(HomePage, {
      stubs: ['HomeTemplate'],
      mocks: {
        context: {
          store: {
            dispatch: mockIndex
          }
        }
      }
    })
  })

  it('should call vuex action to fetch categories', () => {
    expect(mockIndex).toHaveBeenCalledWith('categories/index')
  })
})
```

but it still doesn't work,
[image]

could someone help me make it work properly?

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetch` is a hook that is specific to Nuxt. `@vue/test-utils` is unaware of it, `mockIndex` isn't expected to be called in tests, unless the hook is called explicitly.

It should be:

```
const context = {
  store: {
    dispatch: mockIndex
  }
};

await HomePage.options.fetch(context);
expect(mockIndex).toBeCalledWith(...)
```

Comment: thanks for responding, it works [https://prnt.sc/t1zht1](https://prnt.sc/t1zht1), i would like to know if it is the best way to do it works

Comment: I guess it is for isolated unit tests. You just assume that Nuxt works like it does and don't take Nuxt-specific parts into account. For functional tests, it may be better to test the behaviour with real Nuxt. See docs for the example, https://nuxtjs.org/examples/testing/ . For full coverage you may want both unit and functional tests.